# SharePoint Online Column Formatting - Conditional Bing Maps

Tags: json, formatting, sharepoint-online

I have a SPO list with a column called "PortOfOrigin", I've added a JSON to format its display, the current code works and correctly displays Bing Maps when the column holds values such as "London, England", for example.

The problem is obvious here, nothing breaks the link and causes a 404 showing the broken link (HTTP 404), how do I fix this code to not show a link when there are no values (blanks)?

```
{
   "$schema": "http://columnformatting.sharepointpnp.com/columnFormattingSchema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "style": {
       "border": "2px solid #666666",
       "width": "128px",
       "height": "64px"
   },
   "children": [
   {
       "elmType": "a",
       "attributes": {
       "href": "=if( @currentField != '', 'https://www.bing.com/maps?where='+'@currentField','')",
       "target": "_blank"
       },
       "style": {
           "height": "100%"
       },
       "children": [
       {
           "elmType": "img",
           "attributes": {
           "src": "=if( @currentField != '', 'https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/Road/'+'@currentField'+'?mapSize=128,64'+'&key=XXXX' , '')"
           }
       }
       ]
   }
   ]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to incorporate the IF function to evaluate the contents and look for the empty field (@currentField), if it is empty, then shows nothing!

Can it be improved? I hope so, but this is my best so far

```
{
    "$schema": "http://columnformatting.sharepointpnp.com/columnFormattingSchema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
      "border": "=if( @currentField != '', '2px solid #666666','')",
      "width": "=if( @currentField != '', '128px','')",
      "height": "=if( @currentField != '', '64px','')"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "a",
        "attributes": {
          "href": "=if( @currentField != '', 'https://www.bing.com/maps?where='+'@currentField','')",
          "target": "_blank",
          "title": "@currentField"
        },
        "style": {
          "height": "100%"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "img",
            "attributes": {
              "src": "=if( @currentField != '', 'https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/Road/'+'@currentField'+'?mapSize=128,64'+'&key=xxxxx' , '')"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```